# Not receiving flurry events on Flurry server debug console with Flurry version 14.4.0 for Android

Tags: android, flurry

We are seeing an issue that after we update the Flurry version from 13.3.0 to 14.4.0 in our Android app:  If the older app veriosn (using FLurry 13.3.0) is installed first, and then updated to the new app version (using Flurry version 14.4.0), then we can see that the Flueey events are received on the Flurry server on the debug console.

However, if the app is un-installed first, and the install the new app version (using FLurry 14.4.0) is installed from scratch, we just can not see any events received on the debug console on the Flurry server.

Have anyone seen this issue before?  Wondering if this is a know issue with FLurry 14.4.0.

Thanks

Have tried the steps as described above.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest the following:

1. Go to dev.flurry.com and login with your credentials.
2. On the left side of the menu, click on the wrench button (admin).
3. Under manage, go to test devices.
4. Delete the one which is currently registered to look at the debug console.
5. On your device, reset the google advertising ID.
6. Register your device again with the new google advertising ID + your android app name.
7. Send sessions via your android app which is using SDK v14.4.0 by firing events and then backgrounding app for > 10 seconds.
8. You should see the sent sessions + fired events under the analytics debug console.

The above steps should help resolve the issue for you on the flurry debug console, thank you.